# Can Wakanda’s intended real-world location be pinpointed by the Snap?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, the Snap Thanos did emanates from somewhere in East Africa on the hologlobe.

Has anyone used this to work out a more precise real-world location for Wakanda?

Comment: Are you asking about locating where the origin of the magical phenomenon occurred, or about finding out where the country Wakanda is located through the origin of where the magical phenomenon occurred? Or are you asking if the infinity gauntlet can be used as a GPS?

Comment: Sounds like the 2nd depends on the first, so both I guess.

Comment: If you just want to know where Wakanda is, a map is shown in Civil War: https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/File:Map_of_Wakanda.png

Comment: Thanos snapped his fingers in Wakanda in _Infinity War_, but by that point, I don’t think the Wakandans are trying to keep their nation’s location a secret any more.

Comment: Indeed, the existence (and thus location) is well known. They send officials to a UN meeting after all. Getting in is another matter. Firstly it's hidden (still, AFAIK) and they have hella border control.

Comment: I guess the question would then be whether if what is seen matches what is known.

Comment: Wakanda was never secret in the MCU. I mean, even Howard Stark got (stole?) some vibranium from them around the second world war, and there was reporting about them on television. What was secret was the extent of their vibranium deposits and their level of magitechnological development.

Comment: @user14094230 “I guess the question would then be whether if what is seen matches what is known” — if you could clarify what you mean by that, and edit it into your question, we can get this thing going.

Comment: I'm asking if the location of wakanda has been found from the globe, that's it.  How is that not clear?

If it's to verify the location in another way, ok, but that doesn't change the question.

Comment: The snap occurred in infinity war but the globe showing it happened in endgame

Comment: @user14094230 - The question is entirely clear and answerable (and indeed now answered)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the image seen in *Endgame* we can plot the epicentre (and hence the location of Wakanda) quite closely, approximately 10-20 miles from Lake Turkana on the border of Ethiopia and Kenya.

[image]

[image]

As has been noted, this isn't *quite* [where Wakanda is supposed to be](https://mculocationscout.com/2020/09/14/wakanda-mcu-location-scout/) (e.g. [right on top of Lake Turkana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akwNt.jpg)), but it's pretty darned close. I think we can forgive Rocket for not taking the time to make his PowerPoint presentation totally accurate.

Comment: I had to find a bigger world map to check whether or not the top red line was drawn "properly", because the one on the globe starts from the frontier between Spain and France, whereas the one from the map starts from Sardinia. After checking on a map, I can confirm that if the line was drawn further, it would land exactly between Spain and France. Now, the only question that's left to be answered is: do these lines drawn on top of a globe, translate perfectly into a flat map? I'm guessing It's probably very close.

Comment: I think it's the intersection that matters